# Angular Material 2 : How to overwrite Dialog max-width to 100vw?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create 100% width Dialog. But As the original settings, it is restricted to 80vw.

```css
.mat-dialog-container{
  max-width:80vw;
}
```

I have tried following ways to overwrite this value. **But they weren't successful.**

```css
.mat-dialog-container {
  max-width: none;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And

```css
.mat-dialog-container {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Someone please advise me how to overwrite 80vw to 100vw. Thank you.

Comment: There is a whole discussion discussing the problem [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3239)

Comment: try being more specific with the dom element. http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/

Comment: Are you using material design and trying to override default class? You need to use more specific css rule. Target this from parent element and then try, !important may also be helpful.

Comment: Please change the accepted anser to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328008/586609 since it offers currently working solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add a css class in your global `styles.css` e.g.

```css
.full-width-dialog .mat-dialog-container {
  max-width: 100vw !important;
}
```

.. then provide the `panelClass` to your dialog:

```js
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {panelClass: 'full-width-dialog'})
```

Read this [documentation](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/customizing-component-styles.md).

Comment: I've tried this, width: 100vw; is not working.  The solution is working with max-width: 100vw !important;

Comment: This is not actual answer anymore. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328008/586609

Comment: Does this still work because I would rather do it in CSS so I have something different for each breakpoint

Comment: Lose the curly brackets and it works... you can also add customer data... const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, panelClass: 'full-width-dialog'. data: {someKey: 'some data val');

Answer (score 61):

Easiest way to solve this:

```js
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
        width: '100vw',
        maxWidth: '100vw',
    }
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, To post code as code, indent it by 4 spaces or select it then press ctrl+K

Comment: This is the correct answer! Avoid using `!important`!

Comment: I wish there was a css way to do this so I can do something different in a responsive website via CSS

Answer (score 18):

Try to use the property name directly as below:

```
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {maxWidth: '100vw !important'});
```

This works for me in Angular 7.

Comment: Thanks, was pounding my head against the wall for a day on this! The accepted answer does not seem to work, at least in Angular 7.

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer valid for angular 9 as well

Answer (score 2):

you can set default options:

`{ provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { maxWidth: '95vw', hasBackdrop: true } },`

Answer (score 2):

I need to do this with CSS because I need it bootstrap responsive. This worked for me with NgMaterial 12.2.0

```
    ***in my code
    this.dialog.open(TaskItemModalComponent, {
          panelClass:'d2x-dialog-panel',
          data: taskItem,
          disableClose: true
        });   


    ***in my styles.scss
    .d2x-dialog-panel {
      max-width: 450px !important;
    }

  @include for-xsmall() {
        .d2x-dialog-panel {
        max-width: 100vw !important;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to set things in css, then I can use different settings for responsive design.

I found myself having to use `!important` just to circumvent the default 90vw.

Turns out if you put `maxWidth: undefined` it won't do that.

```
dialog.open(DialogChoicesComponent, { ...options, maxWidth: undefined });
```

As for setting css that's a whole other topic, but you can set a `backdropClass` and `panelClass` and style them as you wish.

Comment: In angular8 dialog.open(DialogChoicesComponent, { ...options, maxWidth: '95%' });  works without !important for me

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by two ways:

1. create a css class `className` and set `max-width: 100vw` ( don't restrict with `mat-dialog-container` because sometime `cdk-overlay` selector max-width is different.
2. Pass as a property or config on the time of Dialog open
   `this.dialog.open(MyComponent, {maxWidth: '100vw'});` and do not forget to set actual width.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your dialog component css add this. Its working on angular 16.

```
::ng-deep {
   .cdk-overlay-pane {
       max-width: 100vw !important;
       max-height: 100h !important;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using material design and trying to override default class? 
You need to use more specific css rule. Target this from parent element and then try, `!important` may also be helpful.

Comment: Avoid using !important

Comment: Unfortunately, as of this date, Angular Material is specifying a max-width in the *style* of the element. `!important` is the only way to override it. :(